# Oracle Trigger that will update tables in a different DSN

Tags: oracle, triggers

During update or insert on 1 table, is there a way to update a table that is on a different DSN? I want to interface 2 systems that are using different databases and would like to have a trigger that could do such updates. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [database link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_5005.htm) from one Oracle database to the other one.  This gives you access to reference remote tables from within your trigger.

This solution has a the merits of simplicity but is not the most efficient (consider bulk updates) or robust (consider downtime of the remote database).

Oracle Replication is a full-on solution that allows you to trade-off consistency, availability , performance, etc.